# My manager refused to change my vacation time. What should I do?

Tags: management

I was approved for vacation but I had to change the date twice due to work schedule on my husbands part. I asked my supervisor if she could change the dates of my PTO both times. However, she did change it the first time which was in January. The Second date I had to scheduled that needs to be canceled is in April. She denied that. Is there something I can do about this? P.S. I received work hour payment for January along with my PTO because she didn't cancel.

Comment: `Is there something I can do about this?` .. how about talk to the HR?

Comment: New here, but I guess your question could use some precisions, such as your country, for people to know what are the local laws about that.

Comment: Did you husband get approval for his vacation at the same time as you asked for yours?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there something I can do about this ?

Not a lot. Your husband's work schedule is not the problem of your employer. They accommodated you once and now you asked to reschedule this again. How often do you plan to repeat this?

The solution here is to pick a data that works for both you and your husband and then stick with it.